# I am converting a .Net Framework 4.7.2 WebApi to asp.net Core3.0 and need to use Http.Sys with its listener set to an item in appsettings.json

Tags: appsettings, asp.net-core-3.0

I have seen a number of solutions for .Net Core 2 that I cannot seem to translate to 3.0. In most cases they do not use the Templated Program and Startup, but are purpose-built.
I use the WebApi template supplied in Visual Studio 2019 Community (latest patches).
In Core 3.0, the Configuration appsettings.json is automatically loaded and via DI in startup, is available to the rest of my code.

I need a couple of the items from appsettings.json, `Configuration.GetSection("OrAppSettings")["OrSvrBaseUrl"]`
`Configuration.GetSection("OrAppSettings")["OrSvrUrlPort"]` to be available in order to set the Http.sys Options.UrlPrefixes variable serverName in the Program.cs file.

I use Http.sys, as the Apis will be running in internal servers, as self-hosted, and using Kestrel, would only run at localhost. Therefore they will be unreachable unless Kestrel is run behind IIS. Http.sys can run as a self-hosted service, reachable across the LAN.

The apis etc are part of a larger solution offered to many of our customers and must fit into a variety of scenarios over which we have no real control.

I probably also need the same appsettings items for configuring Swagger, but that will be done in Startup.

I also need to use appsettings.json to provide configuration in the WebAPI client asp.net programs, but I have that covered, since DI from Startup is all I need there.

My appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "OrAppSettings": {
    "ClientName": "some customer name",
    "AsoAka": "mwp",
    "AsoLocation": "shadow-10",
    "AsoRouting": "unauthenticated",
    "AsoClientType": "3",
    "AsoClientUserId": "0",
    "AsoClientUserName": "shadow-10\\ingres",
    "AsoClientIpAddress": "",
    "ORSvrBaseUrl": "http://shadow-10",
    "ORSvrUrlPort": "5003",
    "EnableSwaggerUI": "true"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;

namespace MwpOrApiCore30
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static string serverName = "http://localhost:5005";


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

                // Services
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                    {
                        config.LogName = "Mwp Or Api";
                        config.SourceName = "MwpOrApi Source";
                    });
                })

                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
                    {
                        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                        options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                        options.MaxConnections = null;
                        options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
                        //options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://shadow-10:5005");
                        options.UrlPrefixes.Add(serverName);
                    });
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })

                //.ConfigureWebHost(config =>
                //{
                //    config.UseKestrel().UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5003");

                //})
            .UseWindowsService();

    }
}
```

My MODIFIED Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;

namespace MwpOrApiCore30
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static string serverName = "http://localhost:5005";

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            serverName = configuration.GetSection("OrAppSettings")["ORSvrBaseUrl"];
            serverName += ":" + configuration.GetSection("OrAppSettings")["ORSvrUrlPort"];

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
.           ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // services.AddHostedService<worker>();
            })
            // Services
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                {
                    config.LogName = "Mwp Or Api";
                    config.SourceName = "MwpOrApi Source";
                });
            })

            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
                    {
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    options.MaxConnections = null;
                    options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
                    //options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://shadow-10:5005");
                    options.UrlPrefixes.Add(serverName);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace MwpOrApiCore30
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo 
                { 
                    Title = "Mwp OR WebApi", 
                    Version = "v1" ,
                    Description = "An ASP.NET CORE 3.0 Web Api for MWP OpenRoad Server",
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "xxxxxx",
                        Email = "someone@someplace.com.au"

                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            string enableSwaggerUi = Configuration.GetSection("OrAppSettings").GetValue<string>("EnableSwaggerUI");
            if (enableSwaggerUi == "true")
            {
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Mwp OR API V1");
                });
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Solved my issue.** Modified after the style of another asp.net-core-3.0 question. Modified Program.cs now provided.

Comment: I'm stuck. IHostBuilder does not contain a definition for ConfigureWebHostDefaults